# Windows 8 power-shell "update-help" is failing. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: windows-8, powershell

Windows 8 includes PowerShell 3 out of the box, but not the help.

To get the help you run PowerShell as administrator and type "update-help". I get this error:

```
> update-help
update-help : Failed to update Help for the module(s) 'BitLocker, NetWNV' with UI culture(s) {en-US} : The value of
the HelpInfoUri key in the module manifest must resolve to a container or root URL on a website where the help files
are stored. The HelpInfoUri 'http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc732148.aspx' does not resolve to a container.
At line:1 char:1
+ update-help
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-Help], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidHelpInfoUri,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateHelpCommand
```

Can anyone tell me how I fix this or if it's not important? I'm guessing that if I don't need help  on NetWNV or BitLocker, that this is the only thing wrong?

Comment: Hey... I get the same error. Now it's personal! Investigating...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they forgot to upload those help files - the URL in the error message says:

> Windows Server Future Resources
>
> 421 out of 739 rated this helpful - Rate this topic
>
> Updated: August 10, 2011
>
> The document that you are attempting to access is not available yet.
>   Please use the following resources to search for information about
>   Windows Server:   For information for IT professionals, see the
>   Windows Server TechNet website and the Windows Server Technical
>   Library.
>
> For information for developers, see the MSDN website and the MSDN
>   Library.
>
> For Knowledge Base articles and other troubleshooting, search
>   Microsoft Support.
>
> For product support, see the Microsoft Connect website.
>
> To participate in a forum, see the Windows Server forums.
>
> If you are a beta tester and part of the special Technology Adoption
>   Program (TAP) beta program, you can also contact your appointed
>   Microsoft development team member for assistance.

Someone also already let Microsoft know: http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/748599/update-help-failed-to-update-help-for-the-module-s-cimcmdlets-ise-psworkflowutility-with-ui-culture-s-en-us